# Google and Facebook login options don't work when there is text in email field

Tags: bug, login

This seems like a bug, I've reproduced it across Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

If I visit the login page, enter anything in the Email field, then try clicking on either the Google or Facebook sign in options, the page refreshes, and does not redirect to the Google sign in or the Facebook sign in page.

As soon as I empty the email field and click on either option, the buttons work.

Comment: This may be deliberate so that people trying to login with their email don't end up using Facebook or Google due to a mis-click.

Comment: @BSMP I considered that, although I'm not sure if the web application should break conventions to solve user error like this. A user who accidentally starts typing in the email field then remembers that they want to sign in using Google will essentially be "stuck" until they figure out that they need to delete the field contents just to click on a button.

Comment: That's a good point. If it's deliberate it should tell the user why the button is disabled.

Comment: Maybe it's a honey pot.

Comment: @tom And if it redirects, would you then complain that you got redirected while you filled up email field and now you need fill it up again?

Comment: @LalitKumarB no, I don't think so. It would be annoying, sure, but solvable without further instruction. Needing to essentially poke around to "discover" why the button is seemingly disabled is a greater annoyance.

Comment: If this is indeed intended, perhaps the Google+ and Facebook buttons should be grayed out as soon as you start entering text in the e-mail input field to make it obvious how you can make these buttons available again. By the way I really don't understand how this could be desired behaviour. Anyone understand the logics here?